# Sat data spatial resolution, where does the XY refer to in the grid?

Tags: r, netcdf, satellite

I have downloaded some NetCDF data.

Using R I can obtain the following information for the dimensions

```
> bio_nc$dim$latitude$vals
 [1] 48.00 48.25 48.50 48.75 49.00 49.25 49.50 49.75 50.00 50.25 50.50 50.75 51.00 51.25 51.50 51.75
[17] 52.00 52.25 52.50 52.75 53.00 53.25 53.50 53.75 54.00
> 
> bio_nc$dim$longitude$vals
 [1] -8.00 -7.75 -7.50 -7.25 -7.00 -6.75 -6.50 -6.25 -6.00 -5.75 -5.50 -5.25 -5.00 -4.75 -4.50 -4.25
[17] -4.00 -3.75 -3.50 -3.25 -3.00 -2.75 -2.50 -2.25 -2.00 -1.75 -1.50 -1.25 -1.00 -0.75 -0.50 -0.25
[33]  0.00
```

Great. I actually just want one grid cell which I extract using a filter. This is straightforward to subset.

I have done this by filtering the data, fairly straight forward.

Am I correct in assuming that the x (`bio_nc$dim$longitude$vals`) and y (`bio_nc$dim$longitude$vals` is referring to the BOTTOM LEFT of the grid cell?

Answer (score 1):

That's not an assumption you can make with 100% confidence just from the numbers.

Check any and all metadata for your dataset. It should define what point the coordinates refer to, and usually, but not always, it is bottom left.

For some data sets there are N+1 coordinates for a grid dimension of size N (eg 71 longitude values for a grid that is 70 cells across). This is telling you the longitude of the grid edges.

If you have an NxM raster, and N longitude and M latitude values, its possible the values are point sample locations rather than grid cells (they have "point support" rather than "2d grid cell support"). Imagery is generally modelled as 2d cells, elevation data are more point-like.

But always read the metadata, or see how it aligns with a known-good source to increase that confidence nearer to 100%.

Comment: Many thanks for your reply. I really have looked everywhere in the bumpf. I think I might work forward on this assumption as variability with adjacent cells are low.